# empty curl-config --ca

Tags: curl

I'm having a problem using curl. Apparently, the problem is that `curl-config --ca` returns an empty line.

What I have tried is to set `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable but this and try to execute the curl command after, but this didn't help.

I appreciate any ideas..

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 20. What apparently solved it was to replace `libcurl4-nss-dev` with `libcurl4-openssl-dev`, and to install `ca-cacert`. No idea myself of why, but it worked...

Comment: thanks for sharing. Honestly, I don't remember nor can reproduce the situation anymore but I appreciate your answer.

Comment: Worked for me on WSL, thanks!